# Wordpress plugin review on Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, permissions

I'm developing Wordpress plugin that allows user to import their photos from Facebook to Wordpress media library, I have created Facebook app and add website as app platform, what do I need to add to Facebook login integration?

Comment: This a very broad question, and as a result, you're not likely to get a good answer (and may be downvoted and/or flagged).  Do you have some code you've tried that you could post?  What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to integrate Facebook login with access permission from user after that you can access Facebook user's media for import in WP Media.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that [this](http://giannopoulos.net/2011/12/28/how-to-add-facebooktwitteretc-authentication-on-wordpress/) will help you

Comment: I recently tried my hands on this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/ which worked pretty well.

I used that for a while before switching to http://Janrain.com

Anyway, you might want to look into the many other solutions in the plugin store:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=facebook+connect&sort=

Even if you are planning to build something on your own, I'd suggest you take a look at these plugins' code. :)

Good day.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here:
[Facebook SDK for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0)

Also check the WP facebook plugin code that will help you a lot 
[Facebook](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/)